# Редирект страниц постраничной навигации раздела с GET-переменной .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Имеются адреса вида:

```
http://site.ru/marks/N_месяц?page=M
```

где N - номер месяца.
где M - страница в разделе.

Эти адреса нужно редиректить на адрес вида:

```
http://site.ru/marks/N_месяц/M
```

htaccess прописываю так:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+) [NC]

RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]
```

но не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: перевод на такой урл: http://site.ru/3 Как сделать http://site.ru/marks/N_месяц/M ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^marks/([^\/]+) marks/$1/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Теперь переход на site.ru/marks/1/3 т.е. сейчас вместо Т_месяц передается цифра, а должно передаваться все значение между слэшами.

Comment: @egoZZZa, а что такое у вас `N_месяц`? Если это у вас не номер месяца, тогда что? Примеры различных `N_месяц` приведите.

Comment: site.ru/marks/3+месяц/, site.ru/marks/4+месяц/ и т.д.

Comment: @egoZZZa, исправил.

Comment: спасибо огромное!!! Помогло!

Comment: Добрый день!
Теперь я поменял url вида site.ru/marks/3+месяц/ на site.ru/marks/3_mesyac/
Как теперь нужно настроить .htaccess?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @egoZZZa, что `3+месяц`, что `3_mesyac` данный `.htaccess` должен обрабатывать. Лучше вам задать новый вопрос, где подробно описать новую проблему с указанием содержимого `.htaccess`, какие преобразования были до этого и какие нужны в данный момент. Комментарии на этом сайте не для ответов на вопросы служат и из вашего комментария я не понял в чем проблема возникла.

Comment: создал новый вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575402/Редирект-страниц-постраничной-навигации-раздела-с-get-переменной-htaccess-и-зам